# change format of date input field in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, date, laravel-views

I have a date input field in laravel. I want the date format to be "D/M/Y". This gets the today's date but i want to be in correct format and when selecting a date.

```
{{Form::date('name', \Carbon\Carbon::now(), array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '')) }}
```

Comment: Do you know that Input type date is supported only in chrome opera and safari?

Comment: Yeah chrome is my browser.

Comment: Actually there is no out of the box solution for formatting date type. You can try to do it with JS to format that field on change.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display this format by default, use [`format()`](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) method:

```
{!! Form::date('name', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('D/M/Y'), ['class' => 'form-control', 'required' => true]) !!}
```

If you want to format user input you need to use JS library like [jQuery Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) for that. It has such an option.

Comment: @steven it's not possible. It seems page is cached by Laravel or web browser. Clear browser cache and Laravel views cache with `php artisan view:clear` command.

Comment: Comes up on the input field - mm/dd/yy.

Comment: @steven I've just tested it and it shows `Thu/Jan/2017` as expected. Are you trying to make this format as default for user input? So if a user is trying to enter a date, he can only enter `D/M/Y`? Or you just want to display `D/M/Y` date on page load?

Comment: Yes I am trying to do that.

Comment: on page load and when selecting.

Comment: As page load it says mm/dd/yy

Comment: So there is no way with laravel then.

Comment: @steven you can use Laravel to display a date on page load like I described in my answer. If you need to force a user to use custom date format, you need to use JS for that.

Comment: browsers tend to use the systems time format, that can cause the difference in behaviour!

Comment: I have did what you have told me and it is not working for the first part.

Comment: @steven it works, I've even tested it, works perfectly. The problem is somewhere on your side.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin: I think parse() is working with this? Piece from this [example](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-format-a-carbon-date-inside-blade?page=1)

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no out of the box solution for formatting date type. You can try to do it with JS to format that field on change.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below tested code, should work for you:

```
{{Form::text('name', Carbon\Carbon::parse('now')->format('D/M/Y'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '')) }}
```